# where statement execute before inner join

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, inner-join

I'm trying to grab the first instance of each result with a sysAddress of less than 4. However my statement currently grabs the min(actionTime) result first before applying the where sysAddress < 4. I'm trying to have the input for the inner join as the where sysAddress < 4 however i cant seem to figure out how to do it.

Should i be nesting it all differently? I didnt want to create an additional layer of table joins. Is this possible? I'm a bit lost at all the answers ive found.

```
    SELECT
  tblHistoryObject.info,
  tblHistory.actionTime,
  tblHistoryUser.userID,
  tblHistoryUser.firstName,
  tblHistoryUser.surname,
  tblHistory.eventID,
  tblHistoryObject.objectID,
  tblHistorySystem.sysAddress

FROM tblHistoryObject


JOIN tblHistory
  ON (tblHistory.historyObjectID = tblHistoryObject.historyObjectID)
JOIN tblHistorySystem
  ON (tblHistory.historySystemID = tblHistorySystem.historySystemID)
JOIN tblHistoryUser
  ON (tblHistory.historyUserID = tblHistoryUser.historyUserID)


INNER JOIN (SELECT
  MIN(actionTime) AS recent_date,
  historyObjectID
FROM tblHistory
GROUP BY historyObjectID) AS t2
  ON t2.historyObjectID = tblHistoryObject.historyObjectID
  AND tblHistory.actionTime = t2.recent_date


WHERE sysAddress < 4
ORDER BY actionTime ASC
```

Comment: have a look at [SELECT (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-transact-sql), specifically the section on **Logical Processing**. You'll notice that `WHERE` is the 4th logical part to be processed, whereas `ON` and `JOIN` are 2nd and 3rd respectively. If you need something that is currently in your `WHERE` to be executed before the `JOIN`, move it into your `ON` clause instead.

Comment: what is difference between `Join` and `Inner join` in this query, and there is no `aggergate`, in select query, cant see a reason for grouping in this instance

Comment: @BHouse, there's a MIN 3 rows above the GROUP BY. (Poorly formatted SQL is harder to read...)

Comment: You would be well advised to include some example data *(both inputs and expected results)* to demonstrate what you are dealing with and what you want to accomplish.

Comment: It's actually quite hard to tell *exactly* what you want as you haven't given any actual examples.  So we're having to infer it from your description *(which, unfortunately, isn't very descriptive; a picture is worth a thousand words, so show us some example data and the results you want)*.  My first inference is that you only want one row in your results per row in `tblHistoryObject`?

Comment: @MatBailie you're quite right my appologies i'll edit the main post to include some example data. But yes i would like one row per objectID returned, with the lowest actionTime field but only if the sysAddress is <4. Currently it returns 1 row per objectID, however it grabs the min(actionTime) BEFORE it removes the sysAddress >= 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH
  all_action_times AS
(
    SELECT
      tblHistoryObject.info,
      tblHistory.actionTime,
      tblHistoryUser.userID,
      tblHistoryUser.firstName,
      tblHistoryUser.surname,
      tblHistory.eventID,
      tblHistoryObject.objectID,
      tblHistorySystem.sysAddress,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY tblHistoryObject.historyObjectID
                             ORDER BY tblHistory.actionTime
                        )
                          AS historyObjectID_SeqByActionTime
    FROM
      tblHistoryObject
    INNER JOIN
      tblHistory
        ON tblHistory.historyObjectID = tblHistoryObject.historyObjectID
    INNER JOIN
      tblHistorySystem
        ON tblHistory.historySystemID = tblHistorySystem.historySystemID
    INNER JOIN
      tblHistoryUser
        ON tblHistory.historyUserID = tblHistoryUser.historyUserID
    WHERE
      tblHistorySystem.sysAddress < 4
)
SELECT
  *
FROM
  all_action_times
WHERE
  historyObjectID_SeqByActionTime = 1
ORDER BY
  actionTime ASC
```

This does exactly what your original query did, without trying to filter by `action_time`.

Then it appends a new column, using `ROW_NUMBER()` to generate sequences from `1` for each individual `tblHistoryObject.historyObjectID`.  ***Then*** it takes only the rows where this sequence value is `1` *(the first row per `historyObjectID`, when sorted in `action_time` order)*.

Comment: This is perfect. Exactly what i was trying to do. Thank you. Helped a lot.